проблема со змейкой на pygame
Написал игру со спрайтами, через классы. При столкновении с яблоком змейка увеличивается, но также сильно ускоряется. В чём проблема?
from pygame import *
import random

#! Размер клетки 30 на 30 пикселей

class GameSprite(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, picture, w, h, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = transform.scale(image.load(picture), (w,h))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def draw(self):
        window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

class Snake(GameSprite):
    def __init__(self, picture, w, h, x, y, x_speed, y_speed):
        GameSprite.__init__(self, picture, w, h, x, y)
        self.x_speed = x_speed
        self.y_speed = y_speed

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.x >= 0 and self.rect.x <= 600:
            self.rect.x += self.x_speed
        
        if self.rect.y >= 0 and self.rect.y <= 600:
            self.rect.y += self.y_speed

class Apple(GameSprite):
    def __init__(self, picture, w, h, x, y):
            GameSprite.__init__(self, picture, w, h, x, y)

    def spawn(self,foodx,foody):
        window.blit(self.image, (foodx,foody))

# Размеры экрана 600 на 600
width = 600
height = 600

window = display.set_mode((width, height))
display.set_caption('Python snake')
clock = time.Clock()

# Змея
w = 30
h = 30
snake_speed_x = 30
snake_speed_y = 0

snake_tail = Snake("snake_hull.png", w,h,0,30,0,0)
snake_list = []
length = 1

snake_list.append(snake_tail)

#Яблоки
foodx = round(random.randrange(0,height - 30)/ 30.0) * 30.0
foody = round(random.randrange(0,width - 30)/ 30.0) * 30.0

apple = Apple("apple.png", 30,30,0,0)
apple_list = []
apple_list.append(apple)

play = True
while play:

    window.fill((255,0,230))

    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            play = False
        
        elif e.type == KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == K_w:
                snake_speed_y = -30
                snake_speed_x = 0

            if e.key == K_a:
                snake_speed_y = 0
                snake_speed_x = -30

            if e.key == K_s:
                snake_speed_y = 30
                snake_speed_x = 0

            if e.key == K_d:
                snake_speed_y = 0
                snake_speed_x = 30


    for a in snake_list:
        a.draw()
        a.update()
        a.x_speed = snake_speed_x
        a.y_speed = snake_speed_y
        if a.rect.x < 0 or a.rect.x > 600 or a.rect.y < 0 or a.rect.y > 600:
            play = False

    for i in apple_list:
        i.spawn(foodx,foody)
        if snake_tail.rect.x == foodx and snake_tail.rect.y == foody:
            apple_list.remove(i)
            length += 1
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0,height - 30)/ 30.0) * 30.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0,width - 30)/ 30.0) * 30.0
            apple_list.append(apple)

    if len(snake_list) < length:
        snake_list.append(snake_tail)

    display.update()
    clock.tick(5)


Скорее всего это вызвано тем, что весь snake_list состоит из одного и того же объекта. Советую переписать код.
Мой вариант вашего переписанного кода:
import pygame
import random


# ! Размер клетки 30 на 30 пикселей

class GameSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, picture, w, h, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (w, h))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def draw(self):
        window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

class Snake:
    def __init__(self, tiles: list[GameSprite], x_speed, y_speed, keys):
        self.keys = keys
        self.tiles = tiles
        self.x_speed = x_speed
        self.y_speed = y_speed

    def update(self): # Перемещение всех тайлов змеи
        for i in range(len(self.tiles)-1, 0, -1):
            self.tiles[i].rect.x = self.tiles[i-1].rect.x
            self.tiles[i].rect.y = self.tiles[i-1].rect.y
        self.tiles[0].rect.move_ip(self.x_speed, self.y_speed)

    def draw(self):
        for i in self.tiles:
            i.draw()

    def key_handler(self, event): # Управление
        if event in self.keys:
            self.x_speed, self.y_speed = self.keys[event]

    def add_tile(self):
        self.tiles.append(GameSprite(snake_hull, w, h, 0, 30))


# Размеры экрана 600 на 600
width = 600
height = 600

window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Python snake')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

w = 30
h = 30

# Змея

snake_hull = pygame.image.load("snake_hull.png")
snake = Snake([GameSprite(snake_hull, w, h, 0, 30)], 30, 0,
              {
    pygame.K_a: [-30, 0],
    pygame.K_d: [30, 0],
    pygame.K_w: [0, -30],
    pygame.K_s: [0, 30]
})

# Яблоки
foodx = round(random.randrange(0, height - 30) / 30.0) * 30.0
foody = round(random.randrange(0, width - 30) / 30.0) * 30.0

apple_sprite = pygame.image.load("apple.png")
apple_list = [GameSprite(apple_sprite, w, h, foodx, foody)]

run = True
while run:
    window.fill((200, 200, 200))
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            snake.key_handler(i.key)

    snake.update()
    snake.draw()

    for i in apple_list:
        i.draw()
        if snake.tiles[0].rect.colliderect(i.rect):
            snake.add_tile()
            apple_list.remove(i)
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, height - 30) / 30.0) * 30.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, width - 30) / 30.0) * 30.0
            apple_list.append(GameSprite(apple_sprite, w, h, foodx, foody))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(5)

pygame.display.quit()

Из изменений: убрал ненужные классы и переменные, создал класс Snake, исполняющий все что было у вас и сделал, чтобы новые объекты создавались по каждому чиху. Попутно существенно улучшил управление. Не смог удержаться и не сделать импорт исключительно pygame, чтобы обращаться через него.
